# Package working in visual studio but not in Job agent

Tags: ssis, sql-job

I have moved my packages to another server. Now on that server when I am executing my packages on visual studio then it is working fine. But when I am deploying the same package and try to execute it both via **integration services engine** or **SQL Job**.. I am getting below error

```
An error occurred with the following error message: "Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\ABC\PQR\XYZ\myFile.txt" does not exist.".
```

**Edit**

Somehow that issue is resolved but now I am into one more issue

Packages installed in MSDB is working fine when I am clicking on Run Package. But when I am creating SQL Agent job for the same packages it is not working.

I have tried setting "rely on server encryption" but no luck :-(

Comment: Is the file even present at C:\ on your new server?

Comment: @stb yes, it is there. On the same server when I am running via visual studio it is working fine

Comment: if the file is really there, this error sounds strange. One thing i could think about is access permission for this folder. Please check, if your job agent user is allowed to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to check whether folder C:\ABC\PQR\XYZ\ have read permissions for an account used to run SQL Agent jobs.

Answer (score 0):

If this is **C:\ABC\PQR\XYZ**  mapped drive connection then use the UNC path it worked fine through the server agent.